# How to get only 'Queries per second avg' in MySQL console?

Tags: mysql

When I execute `\s` in MySQL console, I get a bunch of information. Also the information I don't care about. I just want to get **slow queries** and **Queries per second avg**.

I found solution for `slow_queries` because it is present in the status table of MySQL. However, Queries per second average isn't available in the MySQL status table.

Is there any way to get only `Queries per second average`? I can use `grep` to scrap the information I need in the SSH Console but I don't want to expose MySQL password in logs. This process is automated and not manual. So, the process has to be non-interactive.

I tried to find information in the `performance_schema` but it looks like I am missing something. Is this value calculated while execution of `\s` command?

Comment: "I found solution for slow_queries because it is present in the status table of MySQL." You mean slow_log is a table under the database mysql right?

Comment: "I tried to find information in the performance_schema but it looks like I am missing something. Is this value calculated while execution of \s command?" What value? .

Comment: @RaymondNijland Obviously I am talking about `Queries per second avg`. Whole question is based on that. Maybe you should read the question properly.

Comment: I know maybe you should read mine comment properly.. "I tried to find information in the performance_schema but it looks like I am missing something. Is this value calculated while execution of \s command?" Sounded like you had found a value within the performance_schema database so i asked what value you mean.

Comment: Only way possible i can think off is looking into `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'com%'` save/update those on a table with a event and query that table and calculate the AVG per second..

Comment: No man! I tried that, but it's not showing queries per second. I mean from the values I get, none of them represents `queries per second avg`. I think I have to scrap using `grep`.

Comment: "No man! I tried that, but it's not showing queries per second" indeed thats why i've said "calculate the AVG per second"

Comment: How. That's the question here.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.7

```sql
SELECT Q / T Queries_per_second_avg FROM 
(SELECT variable_value Q FROM performance_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name = 'Queries') A, 
(SELECT variable_value T FROM performance_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name = 'Uptime') B;
```